# document.visibilityState value not as expected with mapTo() operator

Tags: rxjs, visibilitychange

The value of `document.visibilityState` returned by the `mapTo()` operator when used as a pipe with an observable of the `document.visibilitychange` event is not as expected.

```
fromEvent(document, 'visibilitychange')
  .pipe(
    mapTo(document.visibilityState)
  )
  .subscribe((val) => {
    console.log(val, document.visibilityState);
  });
```

Example pen: https://codepen.io/nametoforget/pen/ZEQmdBj

See console log in pen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapTo` captures return value once at the beginning and use this initial value all the time. If you want to have most recent value use `map` instead:

```js
const { fromEvent } = rxjs; // = require("rxjs")
const { map, startWith } = rxjs.operators; // = require("rxjs/operators")

fromEvent(document, 'visibilitychange')
  .pipe(
    map(() => document.visibilityState),
    startWith(document.visibilityState)
  )
  .subscribe((val) => {
    console.log(val, document.visibilityState);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.6.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```